# How to execute javascript pageload event on multi instance web user control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I'm developing an web user control for that i need to set some properties at page load (client side page load). My control works fine with one instance on page.
But when i need multiple instance of that control on same page.Page load event shows effects only on last control.

### My control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControlLoadTest.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControlLoadTest" ClientIDMode="Predictable" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="GridViewCSSThemes/YahooGridView.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
    static Int16 _count;
    public static Int16 count
    {
        get { return _count++; }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        document.getElementById('<%= Hidden_RowIndex.ClientID%>').value = '<%= count%>';
        document.getElementById('<%= txtUC.ClientID%>').value = "Count : " + document.getElementById('<%= Hidden_RowIndex.ClientID%>').value;
    }
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden_RowIndex" Value="" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUC" CssClass="tb10" Enabled="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

### Use control on aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ContextMenuTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="ContextMenuTest" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="UCTest" Src="~/WebUserControlLoadTest.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Java Script Load Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" />
    <table style="padding:1%;width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <uc1:UCTest runat="server" ID="UCTest1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <uc1:UCTest runat="server" ID="UCTest2"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

After execution result will be Count - 0 in first Control and Count - 1 in Second.
But it shows 1 Control blank and second with Control -1 text.
Can any one tell me how can i make different instance of java-script page-load event in multi instance web user control.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
static Int16 _count;
public static Int16 count
{
   get { return _count++; }
}
```

If you declare your control multiple times, then you override the counter each time the control is rendered.

You need a smarter Javascript, for examle, add a class on the control wrapper inside WebUserControlLoadTest.ascx something like

```
<div class="myControl">
   <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden_RowIndex" Value="" runat="server" />
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtUC" CssClass="tb10" Enabled="false" runat="server">
   </asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

and at the top of the aspx page you can have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var count = 0;
   $("myControl input:hidden").each(function(){$(this).value = count++});
});
```

Comment: Sorry to say but this is an answer of my question.I need to know how can i instantiate client side on load event for multi instance web user control(separate on load event for every instance of web user control).I got a solution and I'll post that solution shortly.And thanks for your rpl.